# Remove query param with URL Rewriting not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to rewrite the URL's with params contained looks like: https://mywebsite/FOF/news/page/page1.php?name=petter&country=usa

I think it's not very aesthetic as url and I would like it to look more like this:

https://mywebsite/spiderman

Actually the rewrite work and give me this result
https://mywebsite/spiderman?name=petter&country=usa until https://mywebsite/spiderman

This is my redirected rules

```
##Enabling FollowSymlinks and disabling MultiViews options here.
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
##Setting rewrite base to / here.
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
##Rewriting for page1 uri here.
RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php    
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/FOF/news/page/page1\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /customPage? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customPage/?$ FOF/news/page/page1.php [L,NC]
```

if someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts; please try following htaccess Rules. Where `customPage` is the page which you want to redirect on browser(spiderman in your shown question). This is for specific page request as per your shown samples.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
##Enabling FollowSymlinks and disabling MultiViews options here.
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
##Setting rewrite base to / here.
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
##Rewriting for page1 uri here.
RewriteRule ^page1$ page1.php    
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/FOF/news/page/page1\.php\?name=(?:[^&]*)&country=(?:\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /customPage? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^customPage/?$ FOF/news/page/page1.php?name=petter&country=usa  [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thank for your answer this case only work with constant value ?name=petter and country=usa, if this values are dynamics that work too ?

Comment: @user1887842, then you need to pass these dynamic values to URL itself like: `http://localhost:80/customPage/petter/usa/` by which we can get parameters later to pass it on to backend. With same URL serving multiple backend urls is not possible, let me know if you are ok with it?

Comment: ok but past the params values in the url like that I suppose this is not secure, in case if i decide to past the email address and the password in param in other page ?

Comment: @user1887842, Hi, please do let me know more on your last comment, sorry its not clear to me, thank you.

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late reply, I finally gave up for the settings (this is beyond my meager skill), I finally use post request to hide param (in Url)